# how to display a mesh with texture in RViz?

Tags: rviz, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,
All am trying is loading an OBJ model from a file and display/visualize using RViz. Or consider I have a node that publishes a new mesh and corresponding texture data @30Hz. Is there a way to display this 3D mesh with texture in RViz? Thank you for any help.

Best,
CV

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9299/how-to-display-a-mesh-with-texture-in-rviz?/) by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 284 on 2011-03-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is possible to display an arbitrary mesh in Rviz, but you cannot currently display a OBJ mesh.   Currently you can display a  collada, stl, and Ogre mesh file.  You display them using a marker message.  You can find out more about displaying meshes with markers by looking at the  [Mesh Resource marker](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Mesh_Resource_.28MESH_RESOURCE.3D10.29_.5B1.1.2B-.5D) .

---

Originally posted by [adasta](https://answers.ros.org/users/52/adasta/) with karma: 508 on 2011-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

When the ros answers transfer this question to Robotics Stack Exchange platform they only transferred the accepted answer back in 2011 and left the other (more up-to-date) answers out.

Adam Conkey (https://adamconkey.github.io/) answered at April 2, 2022 with saying "You can display OBJ meshes now with the mesh resource on Marker messages" in answer: https://answers.ros.org/question/9299/how-to-display-a-mesh-with-texture-in-rviz/#398429

[image]